# CSS dynamic max width

Tags: html, css, position, width

I'm making a memory game with cards and I got a little problem with centering.
Each card that gets printed is 192px by 192px, with a margin of 1.5px for all sides, so 1 card = 192 + 1.5 + 1.5 = 195px in width. All of the cards display as inline-block, so when there is not enough space to print another card in one row, it prints it on the next one. The problem I am encountering right now is that the carddeck doesn't center because the width of the carddeck exceeds the amount of width that the cards of one row have. I basically want to change the `max width` of the card deck to the amount of width the cards of one row make.

Example:

On a fully sized window it displays 8 cards in a row (= 1560px width) so I want

```
.card-deck {
  max-width: 1560px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

On a resized window it displays 6 cards in a row (= 1170px width) so I want

```
.card-deck {
  max-width: 1170px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

So is there a way to make the `max-width` attribute change according to how many cards are in one row, using CSS? Something like `max-width: card1-width + card2-width ...;`.

Thanks in advance.

- Ed

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like this:

```
 .card-deck {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1170px) {
        .card-deck {
           max-width: 1170px;
        }
    }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 1560px) {
        .card-deck {
           max-width: 1560px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do I also need to give (position: --- to --- margin-right:) at every '@media only screen' or can I just have that once?

Comment: Please mark it as the correct answer if you find it correct.

Comment: The answer you gave didn't work, tried it out just now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

HTML:

```
<body onresize="carddecksize()">
```

Javascript:

```
function carddecksize() {
  var deck = document.getElementById("carddeck");
  if (window.innerWidth >= 1560) {
    deck.style.maxWidth = '1560px';
  }
  else if (window.innerWidth >= 1365) {
    deck.style.maxWidth = '1365px';
  }
  else if (window.innerWidth >= 1170) {
    deck.style.maxWidth = '1170px';
  }
  else if (window.innerWidth >= 975) {
    deck.style.maxWidth = '975px';
  }
  else {
    deck.style.maxWidth = '780px';
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: This isn't the best solution, since products by apple mostly have a different window size system.